# Google sitelinks

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap

Can I use a XML file to specify which Sitelinks will be shown in Google? For my site there are a couple of Sitelink with the latest articles and so on, but I want that there are only the Categories like 'Mac', 'iOS' or some tags. Anybody knows how to do that?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

> At the moment, sitelinks are automated.

See [Google's sitelink documentation](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334)